# Pros and cons to submit a poster?

Tags: publications, poster

Our paper is rejected, but we are invited to submit a poster. We are given two options:

- Poster with 2 pages proceeding.
- Poster without a proceeding.

Another option is, of course, not submitting at all.

We still want to submit the full paper. What is potential risk of submitting a poster, with or without proceeding? All the conferences we want to target adopts double-blinded review.

I'm in software engineering.

Comment: You should really add the field since conferences, conference proceedings and posters are treated very different in different fields.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want, and can, get out of that conference. I am from sociology, and in sociology proceedings do not count as publications. So I do not care whether I were in one or not. I heard that in other disciplines this is very different.

I attend conferences to network, to get inspired by others, and to get feedback from others on my own work. Networking happens at the breaks, and to get inspired I go to other talks and posters. So for those it does not matter whether I present a talk or a poster. For getting feedback I found that posters allows for a much more direct interaction with the audience. So even though they have lower "status", I found presenting posters often more fruitful then giving talks.